# How do I exclude a source tree from build during a specific ANT build in eclipse but not from normal debug and run?

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, executable-jar, build.xml

I have 3 source trees rooted at:

```
/src/
/srcDriver/
/test/
```

But during the ANT build I have, which works great, except all three are placed into my production executable-jar, how do I remove srcDriver and test so they don't get compiled in?

here is my build.xml.
`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project default="create_production_jar" name="Create Runnable Jar for Project company with Jar-in-Jar Loader">
    <!--this file was created by Eclipse Runnable JAR file Export Wizard-->
    <!--ANT 1.7 is required-->
    <!--define folder properties-->
    <property name="dir.buildfile" value="."/>
    <property name="dir.workspace" value="${dir.buildfile}/../.."/>
    <property name="dir.jarfile" value="${dir.buildfile}/target/jar"/>
    <target name="create_production_jar" description="Create Production Jar">       
        <jar destfile="${dir.jarfile}/COMPANYNAMEApplicationServer.jar">
            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Main-Class" value="org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader"/>
                <attribute name="Rsrc-Main-Class" value="com.COMPANYNAME.PRODUCT.ApplicationServer"/>
                <attribute name="Class-Path" value="."/>
                <attribute name="Rsrc-Class-Path" value="./ XXX.YYY.ZZZ1.jar ..........(SOME 300 MORE DEPENDENCIES).......... XXX.YYY.ZZZ2.jar"/>
            </manifest>
            <zipfileset src="jar-in-jar-loader.zip"/>
            <fileset dir="${dir.buildfile}/target/classes"/>
            <zipfileset dir="C:/Mnt/Users/jamesdmcmillian/.m2/repository/io/dropwizard/dropwizard-util/0.8.0" includes="dropwizard-util-0.8.0.jar"/>
            ..........(SOME 300 MORE DEPENDENCIES)..........
            <zipfileset dir="C:/Mnt/Users/jamesdmcmillian/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/module/jackson-module-afterburner/2.5.1" includes="jackson-module-afterburner-2.5.1.jar"/>
        </jar>
    </target>
</project>
```

`

For Example:

```
${project_path}/src/com/COMPANYNAME/PRODUCT/config.java
${project_path}/test/com/COMPANYNAME/PRODUCT/TestInitCode.java

${project_path}/target/classes/com/COMPANY/NAME/PRODUCT/config.class
${project_path}/target/classes/com/COMPANY/NAME/PRODUCT/TestInitCode.class
```

And I want the ${project_path}/test/ path to be completely excluded.

Comment: It looks like all of your `.class` files are going under `${dir.buildfile}/target/classes`. Please give an example of a path to a `.java` file from under `src/` and the path where the `.class` file for that `.java` file is generated.

Comment: I edited the original question to include an example, does anyone have a recommendation? Or is it not possible?